# Como consumir fazer endereçamento no cliente de uma API que quero consumir?

Tags: delphi, api, rest, restful, firemonkey

Tenho uma API em PHP e estou desenvolvendo um App Mobile com o Delphi Firemonkey, e preciso consumir os dados JSON que a minha API retorna.

Gostaria de saber como eu faço o endereçamento na parte do cliente para acessar essa API, pois estou usando (para testes) uma string que contém o caminho que quero testar. Algo como URL := 'http://192.168.1.3/api/v1/atendimentoscliente/1'.

---

Até o momento, consegui pegar o JSON que a minha API retorna, e estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

1 - Criei uma UNIT para tratar da requisição REST, e o código está assim:

```
unit uRestConnect;

interface
uses
    REST.Client, REST.Json, JSON;

type
    TRest = class
    private
      FClient   : TRESTClient;
      FRequest  : TRESTRequest;
      FResponse : TRESTResponse;
      FURL      : String;
    public
      constructor Create;
      destructor Destroy;
      function Result(Recurso: String; Parametros: array of string): String;
    end;

implementation

{ TRest }

constructor TRest.Create;
begin
     Self.FURL := 'http://192.168.1.3/api/v1/';

     Self.FClient   := TRESTClient.Create(nil);
     Self.FRequest  := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
     Self.FResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(nil);

     Self.FClient.BaseURL := Self.FURL;

     Self.FClient.AutoCreateParams  := True;
     Self.FRequest.AutoCreateParams := True;
     Self.FRequest.HandleRedirects  := True;
     Self.FRequest.Client           := Self.FClient;
     Self.FRequest.Response         := Self.FResponse;
end;

destructor TRest.Destroy;
begin
    Self.FClient.Free;
    Self.FRequest.Free;
    Self.FResponse.Free;
end;

function TRest.Result(Recurso: string; Parametros: array of string): String;
var
     I: Integer;
begin
     for I := 0 to Length(Parametros)-1 do
     begin
          Recurso := Recurso + '/' + Parametros[i];
     end;

     Self.FRequest.Resource := Recurso;
     Self.FRequest.Execute;

     Result := Self.FResponse.JSONText;
end;
end.
```

E e tenho um formulário básico com um botão e um Memo onde está sendo exibido o conteúdo do JSON que eu recupero da API. O evento do botão está dessa maneira:

```
procedure TForm1.btnBuscarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
     Rest     : TRest;
     Cliente  : TCliente;
     Response : String;
begin
     Rest         := TRest.Create;
     Cliente      := TCliente.Create;
     Response := Rest.Result('atendimentoscliente', EdIdCliente.Text);
     MemoAtendimentos.Text := Response;
end;
```

Agora, gostaria de saber como faço para que esse JSON seja convertido em um objeto de uma classe do meu modelo.

Comment: Qual a versão do seu Delphi?... para esclarecer algumas dúvidas, você já tem um WebService em PHP rodando no endereçamento 'http://192.168.1.3/api/v1/atendimentoscliente/1' e você quer acessar esse domínio pelo App Mobile?

Comment: Exatamente. Estou usando o Delphi Berlin Update 2, e o real problema é que não sei como montar uma estrutura correta de classes/units para fazer isso, ou quais métodos serão necessários. Eu consigo pegar o JSON que a API em PHP me retorna, mas ainda não sei necessariamente o que fazer com ele, ou transformá-lo para um objeto de um classe TCliente, por exemplo. Isso ainda está muito confuso pra mim. Se você tiver algo que possa me fornecer um caminho de como proceder, eu te agradeceria bastante!

Comment: Aconselho você dar uma pesquisada sobre REST Debugger, você coloca o endereço e os parâmetros que devem ser acessados do lado do cliente, é bem simples de entender.

Comment: Mas eu consigo usar o REST Debugger, só não estou conseguindo (ou sabendo), no meu projeto, transformar o JSON que eu pego da API em objetos das minhas classes de modelo.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize os métodos **TJson.ObjectToJsonString** e **TJson.JsonToObject(json)** que estão contidos na unit **REST.JSON**